# Can't fix postfix 421 timeout exceeded errors

Tags: timeout, postfix-mta

I am continuously getting 421 "Error: timeout exceeded (in reply to end of DATA command)" upon sending to 2 other servers on port 25.  I have read through many pages, but nothing works.  Here is what happens when using traceroute.  It makes it to the base DN, but stops short of making it to the mail name:

```
root@me1.net# traceroute -n -T -p 25 me2.xyz
traceroute to me2.xyz (me.me.me.me), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  45.11.183.1  3.861 ms  4.052 ms  4.032 ms
 2  212.7.30.161  2.166 ms  1.985 ms  2.052 ms
 3  212.7.29.65  0.863 ms  1.922 ms  2.157 ms
 4  87.245.242.68  0.432 ms  0.599 ms  0.570 ms
 5  87.245.233.74  7.276 ms  7.132 ms  7.093 ms
 6  194.68.123.194  9.052 ms  8.829 ms 194.68.128.194  7.765 ms
 7  * * *
 8  me.me.me.me  8.357 ms  11.145 ms  8.023 ms
 
 
root@me1.net# traceroute -n -T -p 25 mail.me2.xyz
traceroute to mail.me2.xyz (me.me.me.me), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  45.11.183.1  3.933 ms  3.649 ms  3.528 ms
 2  212.7.30.161  1.765 ms  1.736 ms  1.540 ms
 3  212.7.29.65  1.368 ms  1.095 ms  1.395 ms
 4  87.245.242.68  0.624 ms  0.568 ms  0.522 ms
 5  87.245.233.74  6.979 ms  6.860 ms  7.064 ms
 6  194.68.123.194  7.515 ms 194.68.128.194  8.178 ms *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
root@me1.net/etc/postfix#
```

Anyone know why it would stalls out going to mail.me2.xyz?
What is crazy is that it didn't have this problem until I
moved the server to another VPS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to fixed this was to lower the MTU on my server.  I lowered it from the default 1500 to 1000.  Don't go below 500.  I eventually set it to 700.

Show current MTU:
echo "$(ifconfig | sed '1!d' | awk '{print "MTU: " $4}')"  #see MTU

Set MTU & restart network:
sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1000
/etc/init.d/networking restart